# Yii 2 installation error

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am installing new yii2 project.I have already installed the controller .but when i run following command in terminal

```
php composer.phar create-project --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic my_yii2_trial
```

and for

```
php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```

for both this command Its showing error that,

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                            
  Could not find package yiisoft/yii2-app-basic with stability stable.
```

Please help.

Comment: what is your php version ?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you follow official documentation?

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```